# Unable to use dcmtk commands like dcmodify and dcmscale

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1, dcmtk, rosetta

System: M1 MacBook air

I created a duplicate terminal that runs with rosetta 2 for installing dcmtk since it's not available for apple chips yet. In the duplicate terminal, I was able to install dcmtk successfully.

On running `dcmodify`, I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libdcmdata.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/homebrew/bin/dcmodify
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      dcmodify
```

`dcmscale` also gives throws a similar error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libdcmimage.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/homebrew/bin/dcmscale
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      dcmscale
```

How do I fix these errors?

Edit-1: Reinstalling DCMTK made no difference. The error still persists.

Edit-2: I have attached the logs for `brew info dcmtk`

[image: brew info dcmtk]

Comment: Need more info. `brew info dcmtk`, `ls -al /usr/local/homebrew/opt/dcmtk/lib`.

Comment: ls -al logs are too big. Do you want to check for any specific library? I have added ```brew info``` logs though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the terminal with rosetta 2, try adding `export PATH="/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` in ~/.bashrc file

If this doesn't work, add `export PATH="/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` in  ~/.zshrc file

Adding these paths should work

Comment: I added these paths in the mentioned files, nothing happened. It still throws the same error.

Comment: Is dcmscale in ```/usr/local/homebrew/bin``` ?

Comment: Yes, ```dcmscale``` and ```dcmodify``` both are present.